# Show objects on APIView

Tags: python, django

I have a model, and I just want to show the data of the model in my /api/

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Book(models.Model):
    order_id = models.IntegerField()
    isbn = models.IntegerField()
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    order_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order_id)
```

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from filter import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('api/', views.BookApiView.as_view(), name='book_api'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Book
from django.http import JsonResponse


class BookApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        books = Book.objects.all()
        return JsonResponse({'model': list(books)})
```

I get the following error: 'Object of type 'Book' is not JSON serializable'

Regards,

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django models can't be JSON serialized implicitly.

You need a serializer to convert the model into a representation that is JSON serializable (primitive dicts, lists, numbers, strings, etc)

Django rest framework serializer docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    order_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    isbn = serializers.CharField()
    ...

class BookApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        books = Book.objects.all()

        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)

        return JsonResponse({'model': serializer.data})
```

Answer (score 1):

Man... You need a 'Serializer' before send the data to the view!
The Serializez class get the abstract data from the django ORM and parse the data easily to JSON.

Create a file serializers.py at the same level of view.py
and:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

After you create the SerializerBook class, import this on your view and pass the book queryset as the first parameter of the BookSerializer.

```
...
class BookApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        books = Book.objects.all()
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define `serializer` to convert the model instance data to respective JSON data, So define a `serializer.py` as below

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Book
```

```
then in your view, change as below,<br>
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Book


class BookApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        booksqueryset = Book.objects.all()
        serializer = BookSerializer(booksqueryset, many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Read this [DRF ModelSerializer Official Doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) for more details